# Config nsq.io with public IP

Tags: publish-subscribe, nsq

I am using http://nsq.io/ for pub/sub in our system.

Currently, we just use Nsq.io for local server only, I public a message use localhost as:

```
$ curl -d "<message>" http://127.0.0.1:4151/pub?topic=name
```

I plan to use Nsq.io in public server and want to use as:

```
$ curl -d "<message>" http://ip-address:4151/pub?topic=name
```

I can't find document or guide to config like this, anyone have experience to advice me?

Thank in advance.

Comment: [The documentation](http://nsq.io/components/nsqd.html) suggests that `nsqd` will listen on all available interfaces, so all you have to do is somehow open up port 4151 to the outside world, which is beyond the scope of SO. However, be VERY aware of any security issues that may result from exposing your server to the outside.

Comment: Thanks, I try to test open to public first.